# Filtering on value and deleting visible rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that doesn't work like I think it would.  It is supposed to filter on column AL for "1", then delete all rows that are visible, then show all rows afterwards.  My data starts in column P and I counted that column AL is 23 columns away from P so I put 23 for the field. I have headers in the first 3 rows so I have set it to offset 3 rows.

When I run it, it says

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

I'm a beginner at VBA so I'm still learning but I'm just not sure what part of this is causing the error.  I tried everything I could think of to my limited ability.  As far as I can tell...it should work based on Googling other people's code that was similar.

This is the section of code in question:

```
Sub copypaste()

Dim c As Range
Dim IRow As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim rSource As Range
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim endrow As Long


Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


With wsO

wsO.Range("AL" & Lines).AutoFilter Field = 22, Criteria1:="1"
wsO.Range("AL" & Lines).Offset(3, 0).SpecialCells _
(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
wsO.ShowAllData

End With
```

Comment: Your problem is this: `wsO.Range("AL" & Lines)` you have not declared or assigned a value to `Lines`.  Also you will want to include the whole range of the table and not just that one column: `wsO.Range("A1:AL" & Lines)` but you need to put a value in Lines.

Comment: What is the variable "lines"?

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm not sure what value Lines should be...that part I inserted from someone else's code.  If I remove the Lines and adjust it to be `wsO.Range("A1:AL") I still receive the same error.  Is there another issue with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

> `wsO.Range("AL" & Lines)`

You have not declared or assigned a value to `Lines`.

Also you will want to include the whole range of the table and not just that one column:

```
wsO.Range("P2:AL" & Lines)
```

So:

```
Sub copypaste()

Dim c As Range
Dim IRow As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim rSource As Range
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim endrow As Long
Dim Lines As Long

Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


With wsO
    Lines = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("P13:AL" & Lines).AutoFilter field:=23, Criteria1:="1"
    On Error Resume Next
        .Range("P14:AL" & Lines).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error Goto 0
    .ShowAllData
End With
```

Comment: I have tried to run your code now - it looks like it worked but now something else is off.  I'm getting the error "AutoFilter method of Range class failed"

Comment: Missing a `:` and AL is the 23 column in the area not the 22nd.  @JDoe

Comment: When I run the new code, it pops up "No cells found" then after clicking OK, it filters column AL for "1" but does not delete those rows then does not show all rows after.  My headers are located on P12:AC13 so I changed the `P2:AL` to be `P13:AL` and `P3:AL` to `P14:AL`.  Would that have screwed it up?

Comment: The code above works for me, without issue, so I don't know what problems you are having. @JDoe

Comment: I clicked debug upon error and it highlights this line: `.Range("P14:AL" & Lines).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: yes for some reason it is not finding any `1` in the column so when it filters there are no visible rows. @JDoe

Comment: ahhhh that explains it...is there a code I can add so that if there is no `1` in the column, continue onto the next line of code?  I did not include the full code here because it involves work related information.